# Why won't the alert box work in my function?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to take the data collected from a modal window, and save it for later use. However, when I'm writing a function to collect the data, I'm using an alert to show if the function executed properly. When I place an alert at the beginning of the `submitRegister` function, it works, but it doesn't at the bottom.

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function () {
  modal.style.display = "block";
};

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function () {
  modal.style.display = "none";
};

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function (event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
};

//read & write debate registration
function submitRegister() {
  // alert("This is working");
  var discName = document.getElementById('discordName').value;
  var userEmail = document.getElementById('user Email').value;

  const now = new Date();
  now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() - now.getTimezoneOffset());
  var userDT = document.getElementById('userDateTime').value = now.toISOString().slice(0, 16);

  var positionSelect = document.getElementById('debatePosition');
  var userPosition = positionSelect.options[positionSelect.selectedIndex].text;

  var debateTypeSelect = document.getElementById('debateType');
  var userDebateType = debateTypeSelect.options[debateTypeSelect.selectedIndex].text;
  
  var fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
  var s = fso.CreateTextFile("C:/Users/rishu1/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/Debate-App/DebateParticipants.txt", True);

  s.writeline("Discord Username" + discName);
  s.writeline("Email:" + userEmail);

  s.writeline("-----------------------------\n");
  s.Close();
  alert("This is working");
  alert("Your submission to register for a debate has been successful! We will contact you with the date & time for the session soon, good luck!");
  // const user = {
  //   "Discord Username" : discName,
  //   "Email" : userEmail,
  //   "DateTime" : userDT,
  //   "Position" : userPosition,
  //   "Debate Type" : userDebateType
  // }
  // const data = JSON.stringify(user)
  }
```

```
<form action="/HomePage.html">
                <input onclick="submitRegister()" type="submit" value="Submit">
              </form>
```

I've tried debugging it, and commenting sections at a time. When everything else in the function is commented, the alerts trigger, but if anything else is not, something stops it from triggering. I can't figure out what.

Comment: `CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");` <-- This is an IE-only **VBScript** feature that was never allowed in web-pages because web-pages should never have unfettered access to your filesystem. The JScript equivalent of `CreateObject` is `new ActiveXObject` - so your script is doubly-wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Is something in your code maybe throwing an error? Have you seen anything in the console?

That might keep the rest of the function from executing and therefore not calling the `alert` in the bottom.

Not sure what these two rows do, but they look like something that could error out if your code does not have permission to create a file.

```js
var fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
var s = fso.CreateTextFile("C:/Users/rishu1/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/Debate-App/DebateParticipants.txt", True);
```

Comment: There are errors in the console whenever this function is running, and those lines were failed attempts at trying to write to a textfile in javascript. I tried commenting those, but it didn't change the outcome